# iterm2 mac (v3.1.5) not opening in current desktop with hotkey

Tags: macos, desktop, hotkeys, iterm

My iterm (v3.1.5) on mac (High Sierra 10.13.2) doesn't open in my current desktop anymore.

Well, basically, if I start the app from one of my desktops, it opens in this desktop, but then if I use the Hotkey to make it appear/disappear, it always shows in the desktop from where I started it; not in my current one.

It's quite bothering as it redirects me to the one desktop from where I started the app everytime I want to use it.

I'm using a personal profile with the following configuration:
Screen: Screen with cursor
Space: Current space

I've tried to change these settings but doesn't seem to help...

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Within your custom hot-key window Profile, and then within the `Window` tab, set the `Space` setting to `All Spaces`.

Comment: It worked but I had to restart iTerm first, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to post the answer here so it's more visible:

Originally posted by @SushiHangover
"Within your custom hot-key window Profile, and then within the Window tab, set the Space setting to All Spaces"

Comment: This has not worked for me, I had it working and stupidly deleted the hokey window profile, I can't get that behaviour back now, it's such a shame, it was awesome but now it's gone, I'm guessing it's a bug.

Comment: @iFunction did you solve the problem? I've upgraded from my 13" 2017 MBP to new one and iterm started to behave in the same manner

Comment: I did indeed, HotKey Window profile - Window - make sure Screen option is set to "Screen with Cursor, and Space is st to All Spaces. This will give me a terminal on which ever screen I am on from my hotkey, however, it doesn't play very nicely with Spaces I have found, it likes the space you opened iTerm up in. On my Mac (m1 chip) it switches to preferred space to show item window, and when closed goes back to space I was on. Not ideal, but I only use one space for text editor, and a different screen for a browser. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

> Within your custom hot-key window Profile, and then within the Window tab, set the Space setting to All Spaces.

This wasn't enough for me.

I also had to uncheck “Exclude from Dock and ⌘-Tab Application Switcher” in iTerm Preferences > Appearances.

[image]

Furthermore, I also had to right-click on the iTerm app icon in my dock, and select Options > All Desktops.

Only with all those settings did it work.